# return fetch_object()

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, while, return

Meu script é uma função(consulta.php) que faz uma consulta no banco mysql e com o while percorro todo conteudo do objecto($qr =  $query->fetch_object())).Se eu der um print_r aqui dentro consigo visualizar todos os dados mas quando tento usar o return para pegar os dados em outra pagina não acontece nada.

Obrigado desde já.

```
while($data = $query->fetch_object()){
                 $data->id;
                 $data->modelo;
                 $data->login;
                 $data->senha;
                 $data->cadin;
                 $data->cadin;
                 $data->status;
                 $data->idSessao;
                 $data->dataHora;

                 print_r($data); //esse print contem todo conteudo
            }   
                print_r($data); //esse print nao contem nada
                $this->data = &$data;
                return true;
            }
```

No outro arquivo onde pego os dados tenha essa linha:

```
$lista = $modelObj->data;
//aqui não tenho valor algum
Trecho que usa os dados de return

<?
        $modelObj->Consulta();
        $lista = $modelObj->var;
        //esse print nao tem valor  
        print_r($lista);

        ?>
            <div class="col200"><?=$lista['id'];?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"><?=$lista['modelo'];?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"><?=$lista['login'];?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"><?=$lista['senha'];?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"><?=$lista['cadin'];?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"><?if($lista['status'] == 1){echo "Ativo";}else{echo "Desativado";};?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"><?=$lista['idSessao'];?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"><?=$lista['dataHora']?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: vc deveria tornar o array e não true e outra apenas o último registro é jogado em data.

Comment: Coloca o ´codigo onde vc chama essa função, ta meio estranhjo isso ...

Comment: Tire o pedaço da resolução e cria uma resposta com ele :)

Answer (score 1):

=================Resolução=====================================

```
while($data = $query->fetch_object()){

                $lista[$data->id]['id'] = $data->id;
                $lista[$data->id]['modelo'] = $data->modelo;
                $lista[$data->id]['login']  = $data->login;
                $lista[$data->id]['senha']  = $data->senha;
                $lista[$data->id]['cadin']  = $data->cadin;
                $lista[$data->id]['status'] = $data->status;
                $lista[$data->id]['idSessao']=$data->idSessao;
                $lista[$data->id]['dataHora']=$data->dataHora; 
            }   
             $this->data = &$lista;
              return true;

        $modelObj->consulta();
        $lista = $modelObj->data;
        //print_r($lista);
        ?>

            <div class="col200"><?=$lista['id'];?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"><?=$lista['modelo'];?></div>
            <div class="col100 center"><?=$lista['login'];?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria a `consultar()` retornar um array de objetos no lugar de preencher uma propriedade do objeto. as mudanças seriam:

```
$lista = [];
while($data = $query->fetch_object()){
    $lista[] = $data;
}

return $lista;
```

Sua chamada fica:

```
<?php
   $lista = $modelObj->Consulta();
   foreach($lista as $item){
?>
<div class="col200"><?= $item->id; ?></div>
<div class="col100 center"><?= $item->modelo; ?></div>
<div class="col100 center"><?= $item->login'; ?></div>
//demais códigos ...
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($data = $query->fetch_object()){
             $data->id;
             $data->modelo;
             $data->login;
             $data->senha;
             $data->cadin;
             $data->cadin;
             $data->status;
             $data->idSessao;
             $data->dataHora;
             $list[] = $data;  
        }

foreach ($list as $row){
    echo $row->id;    
}
```

Comment: Meus amigos obrigado pela atenção,comenti um erro de amador,peço desculpas.Usei o mesmo nome da variavel e momentos diferentes mas como é obvio de se imaginar isso fazia com o valor fosse sobrescrito por isso quando enviava o return não aparecia nada.